# Java 6 : building a jar whose main class package is not at root of the jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I would like to build a Jar whose main class package is not at the root of the jar.

In the application, I've just written a Main class

```
com.gmail.bernabe.laurent.test.HelloWorld
```

I could simply make a Runnable jar from the Eclipse IDE, but I would like to go a step further
=> Having the final jar organized like this

---

Root

=> META-INF

=> Lib

=====> com

==========> gmail

...

---

Instead of :

Root

=> META-INF

==> com

======> gmail

...

---

Is it possible to configure the Manifest file so that the Jar runs properly ?

Thanks in advance

---

Why do I want to do this ?

I want to build a JOGL-based jar organized as follow

```
=> JOGL (subdirectories are JOGL just needed files)
=> CORE (subdirectorie is the core application package)
=> LAUNCHER (subdirectory is the custom classloader package)
=> META-INF
```

Comment: Why did I get a -1 ? Just for me to get notified about the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, because you should not do that: imagine someone *supporting* your code. Or even yourself, two years later, returning to the project: you saw hundreds of jars organised as defined by `JarClassLoader`, you worked in tens of "usual" projects... Now, well, now you see a JAR file. Will you expect it to have a tricky custom loading scheme? I doubt so.

Yes, because you can add one more main class, use it to set up a classloader, and after that load classes from any layout. You will need to keep manifest and the startup class at the "proper" places, though.

The tutorial on class loading can be found at http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Security/Fundamentals/magercises/ClassLoader/help.html

Comment: Updated to provide a rationale on the "No" part :)

Comment: It flies in the face of conventions and specifications. Doesn't have anything to do with licensing. Using a custom class loader just to have an unorthodox jar content layout is more effort than it's worth. There's nothing wrong with wanting to do things your way, but if no-one else seems to do it, you'll have to ask yourself the question if maybe it doesn't make sense. EDIT: this was in response to a comment that's now gone.

Comment: So what I want to do, without any custom class loader, and without any class package at root (the "proper" place) is not possible.

Comment: Excuse me for the comment removal : i thought the question was not accurate. In fact, I want to do this because I will build a JOGL based library, and I want all root folders to represent the library name/ the core application name. See the edited question

Comment: Well, you can always [change the boot classpath](http://www.tedneward.com/files/Papers/BootClasspath/index.html) and have your own build of Java libraries, including a custom version of `JarClassLoader` able to load the jars of your format. I would change the extension, though...

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE question is, what does it give you? Why do you care about the layout of files within JAR?

Comment: Thank you, I accept the challenge. If someone want to work with my code, the ant script I'll give with the project can help him/her.

Comment: @alf (cross comment) : because i want to do the perfect organized jar : one could guess libraries/cores just with the root subfolders. Instead of having several com/org/net/fr ... root subfolders. But maybe I'm wrong, it is complicating development and efficiency rather than giving jar structure clarity.

Comment: @LaurentBERNABE well, I got the point about perfect JAR, but will you ever open it? (I'd also argue that no one will even try to guess: they'll adjust build.xml and recompile with standard layout.) One more idea: given the libraries are not written by you, what's the problem with putting those in your JAR as JARs? That would let you keep all the class loading fun, have perfectly organized JAR, and still have standard manifest.

Comment: Yes you're right, people want code to run with the more simplicity possible. I just want to organize the black box, but it is an extra effort for nothing. I am able to put library jars as is, and in fact I wanted to do so : JOGL jar should have a subfolder natives files and a subfolder jars files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4490/discussion-between-laurent-bernabe-and-alf)